# Unique ID with combination of App id and Device id for android

Tags: android

How can I get the Unique Id for combination of any app id and a device id. So for example, An app has package name say "com.myapp" and an android device has unique Id (that can be  wifi mac address, bluetooth id or UDID). Combination of these two should be unique. Even If I uninstall and install the app again, the same id should be generated. If there are some other apps using the same technique and are on the same phone, there  Unique Id should be different from my app as they have different package name . Also, I should get a different ID for my same app on a different phone.

Is there any natively available ID that can serve my purpose? Any help in this would be greatly appreciated. TIA.

Answer (score 0):

Try This

```
public static String getUniqueDeviceId(Context mContext) {
    String device_id = Settings.Secure.getString(
            mContext.getContentResolver(), Settings.Secure.ANDROID_ID);
    if ((device_id == null) || (device_id.equals("9774d56d682e549c"))
            || (device_id.length() < 15)) {
        device_id = new BigInteger(64, new SecureRandom()).toString(16);
    }
    Log.d("device_id", device_id);
    return device_id;
}
```

Comment: just a small doubt, why are we comparing with '9774d56d682e549c'?

Comment: A well known bug for Froyo (and maybe Eclair) whereupon different devices will return the same ID : 9774d56d682e549c . See https://code.google.com/p/android/issues/detail?id=10603 and https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/android-developers/U4mOUI-rRPY

thats why compare with this id

Comment: Will this technique help me getting different ids from my 2 apps residing on a same device?

Comment: This technique is only for your device Unique id not for your app unique id
in addition you can manually manage for app based unique id using your package name

Comment: ok. But can I have any technique (if someone has already done that) to generate the unique id using app's package name and devices's unique id?

Comment: No any technique for that,but you can manage like
1) concate this two Id in one string.
2) Encrypt that string using some algorithms to get unique Id

Comment: `Settings.Secure.ANDROID_ID` Changes when the phone is upgraded to next android version and factory reset.

Answer (score 0):

To get your device ID you should use

```
TelephonyManager telephonyManager = (TelephonyManager)getSystemService(Context.TELEPHONY_SERVICE);
String mDeviceID = telephonyManager.getDeviceId();
```

Now append your application package name along with it to get the unique ID for your application. And yes, this unique identifier will stay same when you uninstall and reinstall your application.

Don't forget to add this permission in your manifest. Thanks @deepu513 for the comment.

`<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_PHONE_STATE"/>`

Comment: it uses permission `<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_PHONE_STATE"/> `